# Why ls ~ or ls $HOME not working in Process?

Tags: java, scala, shell

I use Process, to invoke shell(zsh), I want to cd ~, or some other dir,like cd $PROJ_ROOT which is defined in shell. But it seems these token can't be processed.
How to solve this ?

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "ls ~".!!
ls: ~: No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 2
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 33 elided
```

Comment: Because those are processed by the shell, and you aren't using a shell.

Answer (score 8):

The tilde expansion (as well as globbing, parameter expansion and so on) is carried out by the shell. Running the process does not invoke a shell so the substitution is not performed.

The only way to achieve that is to invoke the shell yourself:

```
Seq("/bin/sh", "-c", "ls ~").!!
```

*Edit:* my initial suggestion `"/bin/sh -c ls ~"` doesn't actually work, as it will always list the current directory and ignore the tilde argument. Splitting the command line as a sequence like shown above seems to be the safe way to achieve this.

Comment: haha, thanks.I thought I have to use System.getenv to read these information before I read your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can access environment variable with `System.getenv("YOURVAR")`, so in your use case you can do something like that

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> val home = System.getenv("HOME")
home: String = /home/user1

scala> s"ls $home".!!
val res0: String = ....
```